# Google Apps Script : undefined var or function when using various scripts (dependancies)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried to understand this but I can't, I'm sure some of you went through this.
I have a general ***Code.gs*** file from which I call my functions.

Public link to see my code if you need : [Folder with code and sheets](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bldoklWaz3_NbCSIhDTRuQrmLx1rWmDd)

1. There is 1 function (`updateInvoice()`) I call from ***Code.gs***
2. This function is in an other script : ***factory/invoice.gs***
3. This function uses data generated from an other script as well: ***factory/keys.gs***

What is really weird is that I get "undefinied" when calling this function.

If I put all the code from all my scripts in the same script ***Code.gs*** it works like a charm.
So my wonder is : how scripts are related to the others? I thought it was automatic?

**I have made a very interesting experience so far :**

1. I have created a new project and added the code in ***Code.gs***, then adding ***factory/keys.gs*** and finally adding ***factory/invoice.gs*** : and it works!
2. I deleted ***Code.gs***
3. I created a new ***Code.gs*** script and paste previous deleted code: and it doesn't work!

***Conclusion:*** there is something regarding the "orders of creation" of the scripts that I can't explain...

Here is a photo collage to show you what I have :

Image collage[image]

1. the error in the test project is related to `ss` var
2. the error in the real project (you have access to) is related to `keyVal()` function
3. both are related to the same dependancies matter between the scripts

Thanks in advance for your help,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is something regarding the "orders of creation" of the scripts that I can't explain...

Order of the files matter when global  variables are used. As written in the  [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_calling_functions_before_they_are_parsed),

> Files are parsed in the same order as they appear in the Apps Script editor (that is, when View > Sort files alphabetically is disabled). A file's functions may be unavailable when global variable assisngments are made in a different file. This arrangement is identical to how browsers handle multiple  tags in one HTML file.

Also as cautioned by the documentation,

> Caution: It's not best practice to rely on a specific file parse order to avoid this issue. The sequence of script file parsing can change if script files are copied, removed, renamed, or otherwise rearranged. **It's better to remove any global variable dependency on function calls if possible**.

In this case, You may modify the code as

File#1:

```
var ss;

function getss(){
  if (ss == undefined){
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(/*ID HERE*/);
  }
  return ss;
}
```

File#2

```
function updateInvoice(){
  getss();
  updateInvoiceData();
}
```